# empty input value after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this AJAX call that I make after a button click in the HTML code:

HTML:

```
<div id="singlemethod">
    <input type="hidden" id="teachersol" value="">
    [...]
    <button type="button" id="run" onclick="javascript:play(1, 105, 2)"> 
    <img src="./images/green_play.png" width="40px" height="40px"> </button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT/AJAX:

```
function play(mn, id, nofm) {
     for (i=1; i<=nofm; i++)
         getSolution (i, id, mn);
     executemethod (mn, id);
}

function getSolution (mn, id, actmn) {
     $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "ajax/getteachsol.php",
             data: "id="+id+"&number="+mn,
             success: function(data){
                      $('#teachersol').val(data);
             }
     });
     return false;
}

function executemethod (mn, id) {
     var teach= document.getElementById('teachersol').value;
     alert (teach);
     [...]
}
```

if I check the value with the alert it prints nothing, but if I inspect the element with Chrome I see what I expect in the value field. Any idea of why it's not printing anything in the executemethod? May be a problem with the AJAX (I'm pretty new at it)? If you need any additional information just ask! Thank you!

Comment: That is because AJAX is asynchronous. So you won't have a value yet when you call `executemethod`.

Comment: I get it. So if I want to use that value for `executemethod` what do I have to do?

Comment: Please create a fiddle if you can. The guessing game can never help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using `complete` in the ajax call. Here's the working code:

```
function getSolution (mn, id, actmn) {
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "ajax/getteachsol.php",
         data: "id="+id+"&number="+mn,
         success: function(data){
                  $('#teachersol').val(data);
         },
         complete: function () {
                  executemethod (mn, id);
         }
 });
 return false;
```

}

Comment: See my edits to my own answer which may be even more compact.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getSolution (mn, id, actmn) {
     $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "ajax/getteachsol.php",
             data: "id="+id+"&number="+mn,
             success: function(data){
                      $('#teachersol').val(data);
 executemethod (mn, id);
             }
     });
     return false;
}
```

Please change you code little bit you can call Executemethod inside ajax function

```
  function play(mn, id, nofm) {
         for (i=1; i<=nofm; i++)
             getSolution (i, id, mn);
//and remove from here
    }
```

now check are you getting same result? i have not tested it although

Reason because your alert is calling before ajax gets completed

Comment: same result, the alert still empty!

Comment: Inspect chrome and see in input are you getting any value?

Comment: that's my problem actually. i've tried to "un-hidden" the input and I see the value set.

Comment: in the moment when the alert pop-up the input field is full with the expected text, the text which i expect to see in the alert!

Comment: I already had it in the text field. but since i can't alert it i can't use it. It seems that the value is in the field but the DOM can't get it.

Comment: That's not possible i think

Answer (score 1):

A in AJAX is asynchronous which means execution of `executemethod()` can be done before your ajax call finishes.

Put `executemoethod()` in for example success function of ajax to ensure it is executed after ajax call finishes or go one step further and look for promises in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0):

Building on dholakiyaankit's answer...

Based on this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="teachersolution" value="">
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
var teach= document.getElementById('teachersolution').value;
```

and

```
$('#teachersolution').val(...)
```

as element with id "teachersol" does not exist!

EDIT:

also try:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#teachersol').val(data);
    $('#teachersol').promise().done(function(){
        executemethod (mn, id);
    });
}
```

Comment: good point. :) but unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem. I've just mis-pasted two versions of my code i've opened in my editor! I'll edit that in my question anyway!

Comment: Please create a fiddle if you can.